# Burn NFT instruction

Tags: nft, burn

I am looking for a way to burn an NFT like phantom wallet allowing.(using solana-web3-npm)
can any 1 direct me to an example/resource

Answer (score 2):

https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-burn-tokens

```
  let txhash = await burnChecked(
    connection, // connection
    feePayer, // payer
    tokenAccountPubkey, // token account
    mintPubkey, // mint
    alice, // owner
    1e8, // amount, if your deciamls is 8, 10^8 for 1 token
    8
  );
```

Comment: thank you!
2 questions, please.

1. how it can be implemented using a wallet adapter(since don't have keypair)
2. which version of @solana/spl-token `  burnChecked,
  createBurnCheckedInstruction` are available ?

Comment: i manage to init the transaction but it seems like i dont get back the "sol for rent" for the token account as it seems on:
https://www.sol-incinerator.com

why so?

Comment: For maximal SOL return you need to use metaplex token metadata program full burn.

Comment: thx ohad, can you send me an email where i can contract you?(discord/telegram) please? inbox@avaulto.com